# Javascript prototypes comparision giving not expected results

Tags: javascript, prototype-chain

I was trying to understand javascript prototype inheritance in [This Link](https://johnresig.com/apps/learn/#76)

Then started trying below experiments on prototypes assignment for inheritance,

```js
function Person() {}
Person.prototype.dance = function() {};

function Employee() {}

function Student() {}

Employee.prototype = new Person();
Student.prototype = new Person();

emp = new Employee();
stu = new Student();

console.log("Person Object Equal : " + (new Person() == new Person()));
console.log("Emp and Stu Prototype Equal : " + (Employee.prototype == Student.prototype));
console.log("Emp and Stu Object Prototype Equal : " + (emp.prototype == stu.prototype));
console.log("Emp and Stu Object Equal : " + (emp == stu));
```

If Class variables `Employee.prototype==Student.prototype` is returning false,
then how Object variables `emp.prototype==stu.prototype` is returning true?

I was thinking that `emp.prototype==stu.prototype` will also return false as they would be pointing to the same prototypes as its class functions.

Can somebody please explain whats exactly the logic behind this?
Maybe I am missing some point here..?

You can copy above code and run for testing in the [Same Link](https://johnresig.com/apps/learn/#76) provided above.

Comment: They both have different `new Persons()`.  Give them the same one.

Comment: `emp.prototype` and `stu.prototype` are both undefined

Comment: Just to amplify @NicholasTower's comment. Functions have a `prototype` property, but the instances don't. The naming of the function's `prototype` property is one of the more confusing aspects of javascript. It's just an object that new instances will be prototype chained to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that third check returns true is simply that `stu.prototype` and `emp.prototype` are both undefined. `.prototype` is a property that exists on the constructor function; it does not exist on the object created by `new`ing that constructor.

emp does have a `emp.__proto__` property, but this is deprecated and you shouldn't access it directly. `emp.__proto__ === Employee.prototype` will return true. The non-deprecated approach for accessing the prototype would be `Object.getPrototypeOf(emp)`, though even that you'll rarely have reason to use.

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking prototype will be a property of objects created also.

Answer (score -4):

I'f I'm understanding, what you really want is this:

```js
function Person() {}
Person.prototype.dance = function() {};

function Employee() {}

function Student() {}

// Employee.prototype = new Person();
// Student.prototype = new Person();

const person = new Person();
Employee.prototype = person;
Student.prototype = person;


const emp = new Employee();
const stu = new Student();

console.log("Person Object Equal : " + (new Person() === new Person()));
console.log("Emp and Stu Prototype Equal : " + (Employee.prototype === Student.prototype));
console.log("Emp and Stu Object Prototype Equal : " + (emp.prototype === stu.prototype));
console.log("Emp and Stu Object Equal : " + (emp === stu));
```

Comment: He asked for an explanation of what's happening in his code.